# How to change uri in spring gateway via gateway filter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

below are my routes defined

```
        - id: myId
          uri: http://localhost:4010/
          predicates:
            - Path=/test/helloworld
            - Method=POST
          filters:
            - ModifyUri
```

Based on the request , i want to change the uri so that i can forward the request to different host. I created a filter ModifyUri but its still forwarding the request to uri defined in my routes.

Here is sample

```
  ServerHttpRequest.Builder builder = exchange.getRequest().mutate();
URI modifiedUri = URI.create("http://localhost:8999/new-path");
ServerHttpRequest modifiedRequest = builder
                    .uri(modifiedUri)
                    .build();
            return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(modifiedRequest).build());
```

Comment: I have only gotten this to work using GlobalFilters... Looking for an answer to this one though using either a GatewayFilter or webfilter as I do not want this on all of my routes

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why you would want to change the uri.
Normally, you define per route to which host you want to route to.
Of course you can do a path rewrite, e.g.;

```
    - id: myId
      uri: http://localhost:4010/
      predicates:
        - Path=/test/helloworld
        - Method=POST
      filters:
        - RewritePath=/test/helloworld, /new-path
```

But changing the routing target is not possible afaik.
If you need to route to a different host, define a new route.
The criteria to determine which route should match (e.g. headers, dates, query-parameters,…) are defined as predicates.
Therefore, I really can’t imagine a use case where you would need to change the uri ad hoc.
Which specific use case do you have in mind that can’t be solved with fillers and predicates?
Maybe then it would be easier, to find a solution